# How can I estimate the volume of the region inside an open bounded set in dimension n at distance less than 1/n from its boundary?

Tags: volume

How can I estimate the volume of the region inside an open bounded set in dimension $n$ at distance less than $1/n$ from its boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your region $R$ is contained in an open set $U$. Then you can rephrase the condition "the distance between $R$ and the boundary of $U$ is less than $1/n$" as
$$
U \supseteq R \supseteq \frac{n-1}{n} U
$$
which means that
$$
\operatorname{vol}(U) \geq \operatorname{vol}(R) \geq \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n \operatorname{vol}(U).
$$

Comment: I'm afraid that not much more can be said with the little information you provided in your question...